# Which operator should I overload to catch list assignment?

Tags: c++

Which operator should I overload to catch list assignment

```
whatever myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
```

It will be good if you have some example ? 
If I'm to overload assignment what is the argument type I'm receiving ?

Edited: Ooo so it is constructor, what type is the list ?

Edit2: So it should be something like this (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

```
S(std::initializer_list<T> l) : v(l) {
 std::cout << "constructed with a " << l.size() << "-element list\n";
}
```

right?

Comment: The question isn't clear to me, but the closest thing I can think of is being able to use `MyType obj = {1,2,3};`. You'll need a constructor taking `std::initializer_list<>` for that.

Comment: This is not assignment, it's initialization. And you can't overload operators of built-in types.

Comment: @chris, and a copy constructor...

Comment: @eq-, True, emphasis was on the type of the initializer list.

Comment: In regards to your edit, that list's type is `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to define the constructor that takes a [`std::initialize_list<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). For example:

#### MadeFromList.h

```
#ifndef _MADE_FROM_LIST_H_
#define _MADE_FROM_LIST_H_

#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class MadeFromList {
public:
    MadeFromList(const std::initializer_list<int>& integers) :
        myVector(integers)
    {}
private:
    std::vector<int> myVector;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MadeFromList&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outputStream,
                         const MadeFromList& mfl)
{
    for (int x : mfl.myVector)
    {
        outputStream << x << " ";
    }
    return outputStream;
}
#endif
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "MadeFromList.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    MadeFromList myListObject = {32, 71, 12, 45, 26, 80, 53, 33};
    std::cout << myListObject << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o test main.cpp 
./test
```

gives the output:

```
32 71 12 45 26 80 53 33
```

Word to the wise: this feature is new in C++11.